# Codename One - Listener for virtual keyboard opened and virtual keyboard closed

Tags: codenameone

I would like to execute some code when the virtual keyboard (if it exists) it's opened and when it's closed. I'm not interested for a listener attached to a particular text field, I'm interested to execute some code every time that the virtual keyboard is opened and is closed.

For example, can I log when it's opened and when it's closed?

I've seen the method `getVirtualKeyboardListener()` of the class `Display`, but I didn't understood how to use it.

Comment: iOS doesn't work in that way so this won't work. If you can elaborate on what you are actually trying to do I might point you at an approach that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an API we neglected to deprecate when we deprecated the whole `VirtualKeyboard` set of classes/interfaces. It won't work at least not on iOS and there is no real way to accomplish this.